# installing metasploit

Tags: software-installation

i wanna download metasploit.. i followed as specified and got error.. help me out-

```
sudo msfupdate
[*]
[*] Attempting to update the Metasploit Framework...
[*]

[*] Checking for updates via git
[*] Note: Updating from bleeding edge
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out

[*] Attempting to add remote 'upstream' to your local git repository.
fatal: remote upstream already exists.
[*] Added remote 'upstream' to your local git repository.
HEAD is now at d3e5dff whitespace
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out

merge: upstream/master - not something we can merge
[*] Updating gems...
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Rubygems 1.8.23 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 0.3.45
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.5
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4
Using arel 4.0.2
Using addressable 2.3.8
Installing ffi 1.9.8 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.8/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using multi_test 0.1.2
Using rspec-support 3.3.0
Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using docile 1.1.5
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using filesize 0.1.1
Using fivemat 1.3.2
Using rkelly-remix 0.0.6
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
Using metasm 1.0.2
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out
Installing pg_array_parser 0.0.9 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg_array_parser-0.0.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg_array_parser-0.0.9/ext/pg_array_parser/gem_make.out
Using rubyntlm 0.6.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.0
Using metasploit-payloads 1.1.6
Installing msgpack 0.7.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/msgpack-0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/msgpack-0.7.4/ext/msgpack/gem_make.out
Installing network_interface 0.0.1 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/network_interface-0.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/network_interface-0.0.1/ext/network_interface_ext/gem_make.out
Installing openssl-ccm 1.2.1

Gem::InstallError: openssl-ccm requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
Installing pcaprub 0.12.1 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pcaprub-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pcaprub-0.12.1/ext/pcaprub_c/gem_make.out
Using patch_finder 1.0.2
Using rb-readline-r7 0.5.2.0
Installing redcarpet 3.3.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redcarpet-3.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/redcarpet-3.3.4/ext/redcarpet/gem_make.out
Using robots 0.10.1
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using simplecov-html 0.9.0
Using timecop 0.7.3
Using yard 0.8.7.6
Installing gherkin 2.12.2 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
Using activesupport 4.0.13
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mail 2.6.3
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because couldn't find the `mkfm` file. It is actually in the development package of ruby, so this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

should fix it. Then just run `sudo msfupdate` again.

Comment: sudo gem install openssl-ccm -v '1.2.1'
ERROR:  Error installing openssl-ccm:
 openssl-ccm requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.

Comment: but ruby is already in its newest version when i checked sudo apt-get upgrade ruby

Comment: @SatyamKapoor you need a version of Ruby higher-or-equal to 2.0 — you're probably have lower one. I'm not surprised though, some packages in the Ubuntu repository are pretty outdated *(depends though on whether it is LTS or not, and whether the Ubuntu is the latest or not)*. You can add a PPA with newer Ruby, for example [this one](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng).